# How to anchor to absolute top of the page with an anchor id such as #top

Tags: jquery, css, html, anchor

I have a toolbar at the top of my page with a fixed position, and I have anchors going to #top and #bottom.

The problem is, I know just href="#" will take the viewer to the absolute beginning of the page at the very top, however, I need it to be "#top" because of a jQuery script in place. When I place a div for #top right after the body tag, the anchor only takes me to the beginning of content on the page, not the actual top. The issue with this is that the toolbar is over it foreshadowing because of z-index, so it looks like it hasn't actually taken you to the top.

Is there any way I can get href="#top" to have the same effect as just href="#" directing to the very top of the page?

Comment: maybe you can try specifying `id="top"` to your `<body>` element?

Comment: You know, I swear I tried that quite some time ago before giving up on it and moving onto other things. But it worked this time. Thanks a bunch to both posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `#top` is already used by browsers to scroll to the top.. (*just like `#`*).

So if you do **not** have and element with `id="top"` then it will work as you want..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/AkAeD/1/

Comment: +1 this is cool info. i tried to break it by checking if it'll scroll to the top for *any* non-existent ids, it doesn't.

Comment: Just encountered another oddity in it. I guess I'll explain it in more detail.

The jQuery script has no specified anchors in it, it's written to go wherever to any anchor, so #top and #bottom don't need to be specified.

The problem I'm seeing now is, body id="top" does work, however, I notice that when I removed my old div id="top", it went to the top for a second, then jumped back down to the beginning of content like before. It seems having div id="top" in place after body id="top" is creating some sort of redundancy keeping it in place.

My question now, is how to have just body as id top

Comment: To elaborate again, I know I can get away with just #top and #bottom without script or markup, but I have easing in place and it requires the anchor be defined in the code with an id.

Comment: @popsicle, ids **must** be unique in the DOM. So putting ****top*** as and `id` to both `body` and some `div` will cause problems..
You can change the id and use that for your links..

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking. For some reason that redundancy and incorrect policy is fixing it. Having only body id="top" is breaking the anchor so to speak.

Comment: @popsicle, can you post a live page where we can see the problem in action ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href="#top"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body, html').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without javascript?

Comment: There probably is, but you did tag your question with jQuery? The obvious choice would be to alter whatever jQuery script you have so you can just use `href="#"` instead.